# React Native Security Concerns

Tags: android, ios, security, react-native, credentials

I'm building a react native application where I am hard-coding credentials into the application. This is why I was wondering whether there are any security implications between communication with native modules and/or the ability the reverse engineer the application. If so, what are some preventative measures I can take to still have access to those credentials and have them locally. Please let me know if you can think of any other implications react-native has in terms of security.

Thanks!

Comment: Hard coding credentials to what? Store the creds serverside, and create a service that only auth'd users can get the data through.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small answer for part of your question that I learned when working with penetration testers on an enterprise app that I created.  When you hardcode a string literal it is very easy to pull out of your app.  So in order to obfuscate that a little bit one suggestion I got was to append multiple strings together to get your encryption password.  So when the hacker pulls the strings out of your app he doesn't know which ones go together and in what order to get the correct password.

And if you wanted to go a little further, he suggested that I use `[SomeBuiltInClass class]` in the password string as well so that even if a hacker pulls all of the string literals out of my app, no combination of any of them will get to the correct password.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",[NSString class],@"SomeIntermediateSomething",[NSData class]];
```

But even if you do all of this and the hacker has your application in a jailbroken device he can still see all calls and all parameters that your app pushes around, so they can still get the credentials if you pass them in any method or function.  So pulling the password exactly when you want to use it is key as well.  They can also run any method or function in your app with any data they wish, so they can get a password the same way you do if they know which functions to call.

I'm sure there are others out there who know much more than I, but those are some things that I have done in the past.

Comment: so basically the conclusion is that I can make it harder for a hacker to get my password, but never impossible? I guess that's all security is though. Also are you speaking on behalf of a purely iOS application?

Comment: There is never any way of making a SECURE anything.  You can just make things more and more difficult.  And yes, my forays into security have been solely iOS.

Comment: Just for the added benefit of anyone else reading this question the react native app is stored on the main bundle and thus all javascript code is visible. It is possible to un-minimize it but that can be undone anyways. I'm going to wait for a little bit and mark your question correct if I can't shed more light on the subject.

Comment: @putz1103 when things becomes more difficult for any current super computer to brute force in less than one human lifetime, then that is considered secure :)  (... assumes good implementation)

Answer (score 0):

First rule - never store credentials in a mobile app. Bottom Line. Think this has been mentioned but worth repeating, see
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20294/how-should-an-application-store-its-credentials

Comment: Maybe add a more background to your answer from the linked post (if needed, using quotes)?